# Audio wont stop? Love2d

Tags: lua, love2d

So I'm making a title screen that plays a part of an audio file, but I can't get it to stop playing, please help.

```
    function love.load()
love.audio.newSource(SmallDevNoise, "static"):play()
local OpeningSoundTimer = 0
```

end

```
  function love.update(dt)
OpeningSoundTimer = OpeningSoundTimer + dt
if OpeningSoundTimer > 3.1 then
  love.audio.stop()
end
```

end

Comment: I don't see any problems here actually. A source plays and ends. Nothing is looped by default, but you could use [Source:setLooping](https://love2d.org/wiki/Source:setLooping) and check it out if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sound = love.audio.newSource(SmallDevNoise, "static")
sound:play()
```

and then:

```
sound:stop()
```